# How to link three blocks of contigous memory

Tags: c, pointers

In my below code :

```
typedef struct node {
    key_t    key;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} text_t;

void swapping(text_t *txt, char *new_line)
{
    printf("enter\n");
    text_t *tree;
    tree=txt;
    char *tmp;

    if(tree->right!=NULL){
        printf("inside\n");
        tmp=(char *)tree->left;

        tree->left=(text_t *) new_line;
        ++tree;

        swapping(tree,tmp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char text[256];
    char text_new[256];
    char *new_line, *nl,*object;

    new_line=strcpy(text,"hello");
    nl=strcpy(text_new,"world");

    while (*new_line) 
        printf("%c",*new_line++);
    printf("\n");

    text_t *tmp,*tree;
    tmp=(text_t *) malloc( 256 * sizeof(text_t) );

    tree=tmp;

    tmp->key=1;
    tmp->left=(text_t *) new_line;
    tmp->right=++tmp;

    --tmp;

    if(tmp->right==NULL)
    {
        printf("its NULL at key %d \n",tmp->key);
    }

    tmp++;

    tmp->key=2;
    tmp->left=(text_t *) new_line;
    tmp->right=++tmp;

    --tmp;

    if(tmp->right==NULL)
    {
        printf("its NULL at key %d \n",tmp->key);
    }
    tmp++;

    tmp->key=3;
    tmp->left=(text_t *) new_line;
    tmp->right=++tmp;

    tmp->key=4;
    tmp->left=(text_t *) new_line;
    tmp->right=NULL;

    swapping(tree,nl);

    while(tree->right!=NULL){
        printf("the element at key- %d is ", tree->key);
        object=(char *)tree->left;
        while(*object)
        printf("%c",*object++);
        printf("\n");
        tree=tree->right;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

I need to connect 3 node (text_t) next to each other(like a linked list). I used the right node pointer to point to the next node and the last node points to NULL. But seems like this isn't working out as expected. After I assign tmp->right= ++tmp , and check whether tmp->right==NULL , it passes for all the keys =1 to 4. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I'd say this `tmp->right = ++tmp;` invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
tmp->right=++tmp;
```

you *first* increment tmp and *then* assign it. Then you later do a tmp-- and find the right pointer is null. Of couse it is null. (Executing this statement involves first evaluating the right part, which increments tmp before assigning it, then assigns to the now incremented variable tmp, offset with the 'right' member) You should have done:

```
tmp->right= (tmp+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very long, convoluted and plain wrong. It is not properly indented, leading to further confusion.

There are many bugs, but here is a big one:  you do not allocate the strings in the structure, but merely copy the value of `new_line` in each node as you go along.  All nodes point to the same location.  `new_line` points to the `'\0'` in the middle of the local char array `text` past the fifth character. Use `strdup` to allocate the strings in the list and simplify the code.

Instead of bending a tree structure with casts, You should use a list-like structure with appropriate types:

```
typedef struct text_t {
    key_t key;
    char *object;
    struct text_t *next;
} text_t;
```

Incidentally, you should test `malloc` return value.

Furthermore, the `swapping` function is misnamed, performs a very inefficient and confusing task, using tail recursion instead of a simple loop. You probably just mean to insert, append or prepend a node to the list, but the code is so convoluted, one cannot even determine the problem you are trying to solve.